# how to compare the all the files from different IP adress in linux

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script

I have two servers say 123.567 and 789.012 (just for example) and in that servers we have many folders and scripts. I like to change the mail ID (ex, sai@xxx.com) to another mail ID (ex, prudhvi@xxx.com)from all the script and save them to local folder and compare the actual scripts and the changed script.

I tried with copying all the scripts to local and changed the mail id and compared them, what i am looking, is there is way to compare the scripts (actual and the changed) from the different servers instead of copying them to local folder and compare.

Comment: Your question pretty broad. There are plenty of ways to do what you (seemingly) want. What kind of access do you have for those servers? What services are they running that would allow you that comparison? Is it just about a subset of files or every file on the server?

Answer (score 1):

rsync in dry run mode will compare local files to a remote directory and tell you if they are different (not how they are different).

rysnc is normally used to keep 2 file/directory tree's in sync to do this it needs to know when files have changed, it defaults to using timestamps, but can be made to use file hashes as the comparitor.